# SOS -  Repair with keycache на таблице весом 15GB

Tags: mysql, sql

`REPAIR TABLE` автоматически переключился в режим `Repair with keycache`. Мне необходимо ускорить этот процесс, и я не знаю, как это сделать *без* перезапуска `REPAIR TABLE` или остановки сервера. Бекап сделать не представляется возможным - **общий вес базы более 190 гигабайт**, и это VPS, а не выделенный сервер.

Comment: Там что в базе такое 190 ГБ???

Comment: @Ale_x, крупнейшая база автозапчастей. Я считаю, что это не важно в вопросе восстановления. Конкретно в этой таблице база для поиска в бинарном виде.